Convexity of Dirichlet Integral Functional
The following is not homework, it is just personal study.
Let $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and consider the map $u \mapsto \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 dx.$ I want to show that this map is convex. I considered a convex linear combination and expanded and arrived at
$$\int_{\Omega}|\nabla(tu_1+(1-t)u_2)|^2dx\leq \frac{1}{2}\int t|\nabla u_1|^2+\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u_1||\nabla u_2|dx+\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{2}(1-t)|\nabla u_2|^2dx$$
via direct expansion and the fact that $0<t<1.$ I do not know how to proceed from here. My guess is that I am missing a property of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ functions that makes this mapping convex, as I believe it will not be convex for functions that are simply $H^1(\Omega)$. I was wondering if anyone knew how to complete the argument. Thank you for your help.

here are several proofs for the claim that the norm on $\mathbb R^n$ (and on any Hilbert space) is convex: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546945/prove-convexity-of-squared-euclidean-norm

The square-of-norm function is convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so
$$
|tv +(1-t)w|^2\leq t|v|^2+(1-t)|w|^2,
$$
for any vectors $v,w\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I did not realize that was the case. Thank you for pointing that result out to me.
